# Taking input from command input in C and making a calculation

Tags: c, scanf, argv

First poster here, and forgive me for the basic ask, but I cannot seem to get my head around as to why this code won't work.

I'm trying to take to input from command line, and perform a simple calculation, however, when I debug the code, the error message that I created from the if statement shows, and not the result of the calculation.

Here's the code that I have made;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int errors = 0;
    int read = 0;

    if (argc != 3){
        errors++;
        printf("Error: Less/more than 2 numbers entered.");

    }
    if (argc == 3){
        read = sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num1);
        read = sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &num2);
        if (read ==2){
            sum = num1 + num2;
            printf("%d", sum);
        }
        else{
            printf("something weird happened...");
        }
    }
}
```

The values i have in command input is "4" and "3" (without the quotes and a space to separate them). So, the output should be the sum, which would be 7. But I just get the error message "Something weird happened...", which is obviously what I put into the if statement if the above failed.

My guess is it's something to do with my method of using the sscanf() twice? Forgive me, I'm a student learning this stuff for the first time. I have tried reading the book on C and have my lecturers code, but I think I learn better by trial and error, and seeing how it's supposed to work. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `read =` --> `read +=`

Comment: Whay @BLUEPIXY says.  If you ran this under your debugger, you would notice that read is set to 1.  Then it's set to 1 again.  Then you compare it to 2.

Comment: I see! That seemed to have fixed the issue, a bit of research on the "+=" operand and that appears to make a little bit of sense! I guess i'll fully understand it as I become more familiar with the language! Thanks a bunch!